# How to make a program agnostic of the network interface

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I am currently in a student team where we have to communicate with robots over the network. Team members have a variety of linux distros with different interfaces `eth0`, `wlp4s0`, `enp4s0f1` etc..

We have tried:

1. Figuring out the interface from something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/how-to-find-out-which-interface-am-i-using-for-connecting-to-the-internet), and then generating a file with that interface in it, to be loaded by the program. This doesn't work for VM users.
2. Using boost tcp resolver to figure out the interface, but that has been unreliable.
3. Setting up a common virtual interface with a setup script to bridge the default interface with that virtual interface. This worked great for ethernet, but we also need it to work for wifi, and some network cards don't support wifi bridging.

None of these work well and seem like hacks, we could just have everyone pass in their network interface as an argument to the program as a last resort, but just wanted to see if we can avoid that.

Essentially we want a way to alias/link an interface with a common name, and then use that name in the program to avoid configuring it on every run for every machine. Is this possible, if so how can we do it?

Comment: Generally you would just give the program a specific IP address to communicate with, and let the operating system's networking stack figure out what interface to use based on the routing table. Is there some reason this standard approach does not work for you?

Comment: Honestly I would say making it a program argument is the most reasonable answer. This isn't like finding the default interface (which is pretty easy), you are wanting to connect to something specific on a possibly dedicated link. Much like the old days of serial ports, you would most likely need to specify which port to use in that case as well.

Comment: @cdhowie that doesn't work unfortunately because we are using IPv6 and are required to specify an interface.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir yeah that seems like the way to go

Comment: @akhilv Ah, using link-local addresses? Then yes, specifying an interface as a command-line argument or in a config file would be the way to go.